# Console.WriteLine Is Not Working

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm doing a windows form application. I want to get information from console. I found this code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

Console is opening, but I couldn't see any output. I also tried `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string message)` and `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string message)`. What should I do?

Comment: You want to read whats in the console?  Or you just want to display the console?

Comment: Use a logging framework. [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/), [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) etc

Comment: Is it a console app that opens Forms? That is also possible.

Comment: When do you call `AllocConsole`? Since you are writing to the console in the Form Load event, I assume you aren't allocating the console until later?

Comment: You can change the solution from a Windows application to a Console application. This will open a console and your form.